# Rationale for two separate map functions in ClassyPrelude

Tags: haskell, typeclass

[ClassyPrelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude) has two map functions, namely:

1. `map`
2. `omap`

`map` works on any `Functor`. However, things like `Text` are not functors as they aren't generic containers. That is, they can't contain any type, unlike a list. As can be seen in the following code:

```
module Main where
  import Prelude ()
  import ClassyPrelude
  import qualified Data.Text as T
  import Data.Char as C

  main = do
    let l = [1,2,3] :: [Int]
    let t = (T.pack "Hello")
    let m = Just 5
    print $ map (*2) l
    print $ map (*2) m
    print $ omap C.toUpper t
    return ()
```

Notice one has to use `omap` to deal with the `Text`. As `map` requires the type to be a `Functor`, `map f text` fails. The thing is, I found it trivially easy to redefine `map` to work for both calls. Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

module Main where
  import Prelude hiding (map)
  import qualified Data.Text as T
  import Data.Char as C
  import Control.Monad (Functor)
  import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

  class CanMap a b where
    type Element a :: *
    type Container a b :: *
    map :: (Element a -> b) -> a -> Container a b

  instance (Functor f) => CanMap (f a) b where
    type Element (f a) = a
    type Container (f a) b = f b
    map = fmap    

  instance CanMap T.Text Char where
    type Element T.Text = Char
    type Container T.Text Char = T.Text
    map = T.map

  instance (U.Unbox a, U.Unbox b) => CanMap (U.Vector a) b where
    type Element (U.Vector a) = a
    type Container (U.Vector a) b = U.Vector b
    map = U.map

  main = do
    let l = [1,2,3] :: [Int]
    let m = Just 5
    let t = (T.pack "Hello")
    let u = U.generate 3 id 
    print $ map (*2) l
    print $ map (*2) m
    print $ map C.toUpper t
    print $ map (*2) u
    return ()
```

All that's required is to add instances to CanMap for any monomorphic containers. ClassyPrelude already does this anyway with "omap" in the [Data.MonoTraversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.7.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html) module. I suspect however there's a good reason I'm missing about why there should be two separate map functions to deal with these alternate situations, but I'm wondering what that is.

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is with types such as unboxed `Vector`s, where the type looks *almost* like it should have a `Functor` instance but you actually need a restriction on the element types to do the mapping:

```
instance U.Unbox a => MonoFunctor (U.Vector a)
```

When you try to include such types in your system, with the way GHC only looks at the heads and not the contexts of instances when looking them up, you will necessarily end up with overlapping instance problems.

It can also be useful, in the case of `map`, to know that you really *can* convert to any "element" type you want.  With only one multiparameter typeclass you cannot express that the instance sometimes doesn't depend on the element.